# Media Queries conundrum

Tags: html, css

I have searched all over for an answer to my problem and I do believe it is probably fairly elementary.

I have got a mental block with it right now.

I am adapting a responsive template. All new territory for me with the media queries thingies, nevertheless it is going well so far. Although I am having trouble applying a style to one mobile page without it effecting the tablet and desktop pages, or when I get over that problem, the mobile pages are all effected.(I am sure that I am making this all very clumsy sounding)

My problem is actually a blank space on pages from which I have removed a slider, various buttons and logos, that I only wish to keep in the index.htm page.
I can use

`<h2 style="margin-top: -250px">`

in events.htm for example
Which closes it up, but it then it effects tablet and desktop sizes. 
So I try editing in style.css:

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 767px).
```

by adding

```
.main h2 {margin-top: -250px;}
```

(This is included but commented out)

This then effects all the mobile pages.

The two pages are
http://www.wellbugger.me/index.htm
and
http://www.wellbugger.me/events.htm

Help would be great

Hob

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle? It's difficult to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Use display: none in your media query instead of a negative margin and whatever element receiving this attribute will disappear. Remember, it also disappears from the dom so don't hide your title tags this way or your page content.

Answer (score 0):

i Hope You can use max-width and min width together for eg:-

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 400px) and (max-device-width: 480px){
     /*You Css Code*/
    }
```

So That The Effect will take place only in between 480 - 400

So I think your problem can be solved using

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 700px)  and ( max-width: 767px){
   /*You Css Code*/
}
```

Hope I answered your question thank you

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following and it seems to have solved the problem.

Delete Line 209:

```
.main { padding-top: 260px !important; margin-top: 0; }
```

Replace it with on line 209:

```
.main { margin-top-50px; }
```

It seems like everything adjusts nicely at the various breakpoints now.

Comment: I'm glad that resolved your issue. I highly recommend using the developer tools in Chrome (View --> Developer --> Developer Tools). You can use the magnifying glass in top left of Developer Tools to pinpoint the element that is giving you grief. Then you can make changes to the CSS while still in  Chrome and see the changes instantly.